# parse tree results / get childrens

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

I'm currently developping a new application and i need to manage locations (continents > countries > regions > cities ).

I'm trying (without success) to get a tree directly from neo4j using cypher :

```
MATCH p = (r:Location)-[:CONTAINS*]->() 
WHERE r.category='continent'
RETURN p AS path
```

Now, i want to parse those datas, so i can do this way :

```
MATCH (r:Location)-[:CONTAINS]->(r2) 
WHERE r.category='continent' 
OPTIONAL MATCH (r2)-[:CONTAINS]->(r3) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (r3)-[:CONTAINS]->(r4) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (r4)-[:CONTAINS]->(r5) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (r6)-[:CONTAINS]->(r6)
RETURN r.name, r.category, r2.name, r2.category, r3.name, r3.category, r4.name,r4.category, r5.name, r5.category, r6.name, r6.category
```

But it's not the response i'm waiting for and i don't like this solution because there's a maximum of 6 relationships. I risk to break the tree if i do so.

```
[ { 'r.name': 'Europe','r.category': 'continent','r2.name': 'Germany','r2.category': 'country','r3.name': null,'r3.category': null,'r4.name': null,'r4.category': null,'r5.name': null,'r5.category': null,'r6.name': null,'r6.category': null },
  { 'r.name': 'Europe','r.category': 'continent','r2.name': 'France','r2.category': 'country','r3.name': 'Ile de France','r3.category': 'region','r4.name': 'Paris','r4.category': 'city','r5.name': null,'r5.category': null,'r6.name': null,'r6.category': null },
  { 'r.name': 'Europe','r.category': 'continent','r2.name': 'France','r2.category': 'country','r3.name': 'Ile de France','r3.category': 'region','r4.name': 'Versailles','r4.category': 'city','r5.name': null,'r5.category': null,'r6.name': null,'r6.category': null },
  { 'r.name': 'Europe','r.category': 'continent','r2.name': 'France','r2.category': 'country','r3.name': 'Ile de France','r3.category': 'region','r4.name': 'Montreuil','r4.category': 'city','r5.name': null,'r5.category': null,'r6.name': null,'r6.category': null },
  { 'r.name': 'Europe','r.category': 'continent','r2.name': 'Belgium','r2.category': 'country','r3.name': null,'r3.category': null,'r4.name': null,'r4.category': null,'r5.name': null,'r5.category': null,'r6.name': null,'r6.category': null } ]
```

Is there a way to parse results/change my query to get a json-formatted of the tree with 'childrens' like that :

```
[{"name":"Africa"},{"name":"Europe","childrens":[{"name":"France"},{"name":"Germany"},{"name":"Belgium","childrens":[{"name":"Brussels Capitale","childrens":[{"name":"Brussels Capitale"}]}]}]}]
```

Thanks for your help !

Fred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK... I found the solution :)

```
MATCH (l:Location) WHERE l.category='continent'
OPTIONAL MATCH (l)-[:CONTAINS]->(l2:Location) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (l2)-[:CONTAINS]->(l3:Location)
OPTIONAL MATCH (l3)-[:CONTAINS]->(l4:Location)
OPTIONAL MATCH (l4)-[:CONTAINS]->(l5:Location)
WITH l AS l, l2 AS l2, l3 AS l3, l4 AS l4, COLLECT( DISTINCT { name: l5.name }) AS subl4
WITH l AS l, l2 AS l2, l3 AS l3, subl4, COLLECT( DISTINCT { name: l4.name, children: subl4 }) AS subl3
WITH l AS l, l2 AS l2, subl3 AS subl3, COLLECT( DISTINCT { name: l3.name, children: subl3 }) AS subl2
WITH l AS l, COLLECT( DISTINCT { name: l2.name, children: subl2 }) AS subl
RETURN COLLECT( DISTINCT { name: l.name, children: subl })
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a JSON library like the very good [google GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to create the JSON that you want.  Some of these libraries are very good at taking vanilla data structures, and turning them into JSON objects.

So when you execute a cypher query in java, the result that you get back from an ExecutionEngine object is an ExecutionResult object -- which is type compatible with Map.   Essentially, if you craft your Cypher query to return the right kind of data, you can take the execution result and feed it straight to GSON.  Examples of how to use GSON to turn a complex java object into JSON [is here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples).

Your other alternative is to use the [Neo4J REST API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-cypher.html) to issue your Cypher query to a server via a POST operation, and then try to massage the JSON that it sends you back.  I don't think it will send you exactly what you want, but you can get pretty close and then work with that format from there.

Answer (score 1):

With Neo4j 2.0 you can also use literal maps and collections in Cypher, so you can construct your JSON document to your liking, see this GraphGist as an example.

http://gist.neo4j.org/?9269173

Comment: Yap, thanks... That's the closest solution i found... But i can't (for now) get a COLLECT from a previous COLLECT...  
  
I'm using this query :  
  
`MATCH (l:Location) WHERE l.category='continent' OPTIONAL MATCH (l)-[:CONTAINS]->(l2) OPTIONAL MATCH (l2)-[:CONTAINS]->(l3) OPTIONAL MATCH (l3)-[:CONTAINS]->(l4) RETURN { name: l.name, children: COLLECT (distinct { name: l2.name, children: COLLECT(distinct { name: l3.name, children: COLLECT(distinct {name: l4.name}) }) }) }`
  
But i get this error:  
  
`Error: Can't use aggregate functions inside of aggregate functions.`

Comment: and with this one, i get an "Unknown error" :

`MATCH (l:Location) WHERE l.category='continent'
OPTIONAL MATCH (l)-[:CONTAINS]-(l2)
OPTIONAL MATCH (l2)-[:CONTAINS]-(l3)
WITH l AS l, l2 AS l2, l3 AS l3, COLLECT(DISTINCT l2.name ) AS children
WITH l AS l, l2 AS l2, l3 AS l3, children AS children, COLLECT(DISTINCT l3.name) AS children2
RETURN { name: l, children: {name: children, children: {name: children2 } } }`